# Trying to access common Typescript enums from both Client and NodeJS server

Tags: enums, typescript

I am trying to access enums written in a Typescript file from both the server and the client. The file is called `SocketEndpoints.ts` and contains `enum SocketMessages`.

```
enum SocketMessages{
    CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL
}
```

I am able call the enum from the client side by using typescript reference tags. However, using the reference tag alone from the server side (and not using any import/require) leads to an error:

```
message: endPointModule.SocketMessages.CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL
                                                      ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'CONNECTION_SUCCESSFUL' of undefined
```

As mentioned in one of the answers below, I have to use import/require statement in the server program which runs on NodeJS and "export" the enum. However, using the "export" keyword causes the enum to be inaccessible from the client. Please help me figure out a way to keep this enum commonly accessible from server and client with simplicity. I'd prefer to use only reference tags.

As shown in the answer for this question:

stackoverflow.com/questions/14659996/reference-tag-pollutes-modules-using-typescript

The typescript compiler should traverse all referenced files and include its code in the compiled javascript output. But the javascript output for server side programs don't seem to have that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix and match reference tags to implementation files with `import` directives (think about what's going on in the JavaScript runtime - what is loading that script? Nothing.).

Put `export` in front of the `enum`s and use `import`/`require` to load `SocketIoEndpoints.ts`.

Comment: Is it possible to do with just reference tags instead of import/require. That way I can refer to a common reference file instead of having to write import/require in each ts file

Comment: And using "export" with the enums makes it hard to read them from client side files.